# Why does a boost adjacency_list using vecS as OutEdgeList template parameter invalidate edges on traversal?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, adjacency-list

I'm reading the documentation about [adjacency_list](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) and the impact [choosing the graph type](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:choosing-graph-type) has on memory consumption, big-O runtime, and descriptor stability.

Quoting the first link:

> The following table summarizes which operations cause descriptors and iterators to become invalid. In the table, EL is an abbreviation for OutEdgeList and VL means VertexList. The Adj Iter category includes the out_edge_iterator, in_edge_iterator, and adjacency_iterator types.
> A more detailed description of descriptor and iterator invalidation is given in the documentation for each operation.
> [image: Table: Summary of Descriptor and Iterator Invalidation]

I understand that if one uses `vecS` for the `VertexList` that on `remove_vertex()` all vertex descriptors will be adjusted so that they are still continuous.

I do not understand why, apparently, using `vecS` causes the edge iteration to invalidate edge descriptors.

Do I understand the table correctly in that it is saying "If you use `vecS` for the Edge List type on an `adjacency_list` graph that is `directedS` then you can not stably iterate over the edges because iterating over them will invalidate the edge iterators and edge descriptors"?

If I do understand this correctly, please explain why this is the case. If I misunderstand, please clarify the actual effect using `vecS` for the Edge List has.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re misreading it, as you suspected.

The confusion is that the columns “Edge Iter”, “Vertex Iter” and “Adj Iter” are abbreviating for “Iterator”, not “iteration”.

The mere act of iteration never changes the `adjacency_list`, so cannot invalidate descriptors nor iterators.

There are graph models where the descriptors are more stable than the iterators (the iterators. That’s actually the key reason for the descriptor concepts. Any container selector with reference stability (i.e. node-based containers) will naturally have iterator stability (only invalidating iterators to  erased nodes).

The table is useful because for performance on “immutable” (or change rarely, query-often) graphs can be greatly enhanced by choosing contiguous storage (like vecS) and they will naturally impose more restricting invalidation rules (e.g. vectors may reallocate, which *invalidates* all iterators, but the descriptor might remain stable up to the index of modification/insertion).

**Tip**

To get a raw compile-time check on basic invalidation issues, consider taking your graph by const reference. That will eliminate the off-chance of unintended modifications. Of course, in some cases you really want to walk the edge (for performance) where you want to performa modifications to the graph and you’ll have to per-use the documentation to see exactly what invalidation rules apply to that modification.

Comment: Ah, so the table says e.g. that if we use `vecS` as Edge List type on a `directedS` adjacency_list, then the descriptors remain valid but the iterators are invalidated when we remove an edge. That makes more sense, thanks!

Comment: To be sure I got this right: According to the table, if I use Edge List type `listS` and iterate over the outEdges of some vertex, removing or adding an edge during that iteration would not break the iterators. Correct?